# Is there a log of file moves by Mac Finder?

Tags: macos, mac, finder, macos-bigsur

When using Finder I accidentally moved a few thousand files to the wrong folder. They come from hundreds of initial folders. (I might have moved the Recents files.)

Finder does not offer an Undo action now.

I want to move them back to their original folders. Since it's impossible to remember the locations of a few thousand files, I need a log of the file moves to put them back. Where can I find Finder's log? If I cannot find it, could an Apple tech do so?

I'm running macOS Big Sur and, FWIW, I killed Finder in an attempt to stop the move.

Comment: “Finder does not offer an Undo action now.” Yeah it does, just hit “Command”+“Z”. But this might not work if you moved files across drives/devices.

Comment: It didn't offer an Undo action. Perhaps that was because I killed Finder in an attempt to stop the move.

Comment: “Perhaps that was because I killed Finder in an attempt to stop the move.” Sad to say, this is most likely what happened.